# Retrieve number of Mondays in a particular month

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, nsdateformatter

I want to retrieve number of Mondays of a particular month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated what you've tried and why it didn't work - which is the way SO works. Remember for next time.

In finding a solution to your problem ask yourself the following:

- What is the minimum number of Mondays (or any other day) in a month? How about the maximum?
- Can you determine the day of the 1st of any month using library/framework functions?
- How about the number of days in any month?
- Using the answers to the above could you design and implement the algorithm?

If you get stuck ask a new question, show what you've tried, where it failed, and someone will undoubtedly help you out.

HTH